# How to find pressure in a fluid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

The diameter of a pipe changes gradually from 150mm at a point A, 6m above a datum, to 75mm at point B, 3m above the datum. The pressure point is 103kN/m² and the velocity of flow is 3.6m/s. Neglecting losses, determine the pressure at point B.

(Assuming the fluid is water!)
Wont the change in pressure be in proportion to the change in area (A1/A2 =  p1/p2) plus the frustum head of water? Do I need to use the flow?

Comment: Use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_principle#Incompressible_flow_equation

Answer (score 1):

Yes? You need to use Bernoulli's equation for incompressible flow:

$V^2/2 + p/\rho + gz = const$